# Could not compile that if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

I am getting so many compile errors here. How to solve them?

**Objective:** Are some `JCheckBox` not selected? If so, what is the selected item on a `JComboBox`?

```
if (reinforcedBottom.isSelected() == false) && (reinforcedCorners.isSelected() == false) && ((gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 0) || (gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 1) || (gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 2)) {}
```

Comment: reinforcedBottom.isSelected() == false? !reinforcedBottom.isSelected()

Answer (score 1):

You need a pair of parenthes around the whole condition, but you can skip most of the other parentheses.

```
if (
  reinforcedBottom.isSelected() == false &&
  reinforcedCorners.isSelected() == false &&
  (
    gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 0 ||
    gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 1 ||
    gradeOfCard.selectedItem() == 2
  )
) {
```

Written on separate lines for clarity, naturally you can write it on one line if you like.